# Why am I getting faces rendered with no vertices?

Tags: faces

Why am I getting faces rendered with no vertices?

[image]

Comment: What was your process to get to where the image is now? It is hard to diagnose without that info.

Comment: How are you rendering it? - A normal render wouldn't show any edges or vertices at all so I assume that's been done via the View > Viewport Render image menu or just be a screenshot of the Edit window?

Comment: it is through the viewport

Comment: Can you add an image of the Edit window which you can do via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu. It would also help if you could share your Blend file at https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link to the file into your question.

Comment: Actually what you show in the screenshot is not what we usually relate to as "rendered". I guess there is a misunderstanding of the different viewport shading modes and the terminology here?

Answer (score 0):

As @gab already said, it is hard to identify what's going on there without any info about what you did. Just from what it looks like I guess it is something like this, I'm sorry if I'm wrong but then you have to give more information:

You duplicated the cylinder and have both in the same place. You are in *Edit Mode* on the second cylinder and row of faces is deleted or hidden. Since the first cylinder still is in the same place but not in *Edit Mode*, you can see the faces of it without vertices where the faces are missing on the second one.

This is how it looks in your screenshot. You can see that there are two cylinders in the *Outliner* window. I have selected the second one and it is in *Edit Mode*.

[image: both cylinders]

If I disable visibilty on the first cylinder you can see how the second one looks like in *Edit Mode* without the first.

[image: cylinder in edit mode]

And here I made the second one invisible. You can see the geometry where it is missing on the second one. But since the first one is in *Object Mode* you cannot see edges or vertices.

[image: first cylinder in object mode]